# Table inside div overflowing

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a very basic CSS question.
I have a div with fixed height and I have a table inside that div.

The content of the table will not fit in the div unless the div gets a scrollbar. The problem is now,
the content of the table is overflowing the div as its height is more than the height I set on the div.

This is what I have for the Div

```
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 200px;
```

Here is an example.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNS26/58/)

How do I get the table to fit in the div and have a scrollbar? This is not specific to any browser. I tried both in Chrome and IE myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**edit**] Quoting your request:

> How do I get the table to fit in the div **and have a scrollbar**.

Add the following to `.test` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNS26/60/))

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Documentation for [`overflow-y`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-y)

Answer (score 1):

```
.test {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.matrix td, .matrix th{
  border: 0.1em solid #E2E2E2;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  min-width: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Editing to incorporate my answer? Bad form, sir.

Comment: i just got he want scroll first i thought he want without scrolbar.sorry for matching am giving you +1 for same answer.