# overflowed table inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem.

```
<div style="height:500px; overflow:hidden">
    <table style="height:1000px">....</table>
</div>
```

overflowed parts of table are visible. how can I fix this

**Updated:**

My code is exactly like this:

```
<style>
#trademark img{
width:300px;
height:250px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
}
</style>

<div id="trademark" style="height:570px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#F00">
    <table id="trade_content" style="position:absolute; margin-left:103px;" border="0" cellpadding="15">
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><img src="1.png"></td>
    <td align="center"><img src="2.png"></td>
    <td align="center"><img src="3.png"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post you full html

Comment: Please could you share the actual code? From http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvbVGp the bottom border is not visible as expected.

Comment: code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/ttq45194/, if overflow changed to auto, you can see difference http://jsfiddle.net/ttq45194/1/

Comment: I've updated my qurestion with full html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added `position:absolute;` in table so to hide the overflowed parts of table you need to add `position:relative;` in parent `<div id="trademark">`

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: ThanK you... when you asked me to post the full html I've noticed that... 

which solves my problem

Comment: if you don't need position:absolute then remove that from table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `div` should have a max-height in the style to make the overflow work. This means that your code should look like this:

```
<div style="max-height: 500px; overflow: hidden">
    <table style="height: 1000px">....</table>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works. In case, give a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770928/table-inside-div-overflowing) previously asked question.

Comment: Thank you please review my updated question with more details

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem happens when using **position:absolute**

after removing it everything is working fine thank you all...